# How to display list of pictures saved in a path in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I take pictures and save this with a name like picture1 picture2 etc to do this I use sharedpref to save list ["picture1", "picture2"...]

After this, I would like to load this list and display it in a list of all the pictures present in this list. but I don't know how to do this.

I succeded to display one image from sharedpref like this :

```
dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/$_counter.jpg';
Image.file( File(dirPath),),
```

Comment: loop? ListView? if you say that you have a list you can loop through it ListView will be do the job

Comment: sorry i don't know how to loop and what does it mean ^^ but yes I just want to display in a list all pictures I took

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List<String> fileNames = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg'];

  return ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      for (final name in fileNames)
        Image.file(File('${extDir.path}/Pictures/$name'))
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use shared pref for saving the image's path , you should use the property `setStringList(key,ListOfStrings);` & `getStringList(key)` like this `pref.setStringList("StringListKey",myStringList);`

now in the UI :

```
   @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   String  dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures';
  List<String> fileNames = pref.getStringList(imagesKey);
   //NOTE: You should get the instance before this line in the initState function
  // or you will have to use the futurebuilder widget to the instance 

  return ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      for (final name in fileNames)
        Image.file(File('$dirPath/$name'))
    ],
  );
}
```